# php syntax problem. (php in css in php array)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, syntax

i have short question which is probably super easy to answer but i'm with stupid today..

can someone please tell me the proper syntax to close the `<h4>` in my array and explain the correct syntax to me? thanks!

```
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => '1st_menu',
                'before' => '<h4 '<?php if ( is_page('5')) { echo ' id="visible"'; } ?> >',
                'after' => '</h4>'
            )
        );
    ?>
```

Comment: Quick fixes all around without explanation (yet), which is that you are 'opening' php a second time around (`<?php`) while you already are in PHP, to the second `<?php` is a syntax error.

Comment: ha, you are mixing PHP and PHP xD

Comment: well.. thought i had to cause i wanted to insert some css... learned my lesson. thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess something like :

```
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => '1st_menu',
                'before' => '<h4 '.(is_page('5') ? ' id="visible"' : '').' >',
                'after' => '</h4>'
            )
        );
    ?>
```

Comment: Ha! :) To the ternarymobile, Robin!

Comment: nice. thanks! can you recommend some good explanaiton on the quotes usage? i always mix things up when mixing php and css... guess thats why i'm a frontend guy..

Comment: You made the mistake of having too many `php` tags.  Once you have one `<?php`, think of yourself as in "php mode" until you have a "?>".  Within "php mode", you can add strings together with a period (`.`), called "concatenation".  The part with `is_page` in the parenthesis is called a ternary.  It's like a `if` statement, but you can use it in line.  First comes a conditional statement, if it is true, the string after the question mark is used, if it is false, the string after the colon is used. So either way, it will give us a string, which is concatenated into the larger string with `h4`.

Comment: @tobiasmay : No problem but while i provided a copy paste answer @Chris provided nearly the same and a comment with a good explanation. So don't miss an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array( 
        'theme_location' => '1st_menu', 
        'before' => '<h4 '. (is_page('5') ? ' id="visible"':'').'>', 
        'after' => '</h4>' 
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

don't know about WP but that should be:

```
<?php
    if(is_page('5')){
        $id = ' id="visible" ';
    }else{
        $id = NULL;
    }
    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => '1st_menu',
            'before' => '<h4'.$id.'>',
            'after' => '</h4>'
        )
    );
?>
```